# iBook G4r system installation

Tags: hard-drive, macos, ibook

I have an iBook G4, HDD wiped clean. I attempted to install Tiger from the disk. It got a bit into the install and it shutdown, so it did not complete the install. Also, it will not power up now so the disk cannot be ejected.

Is there a way to manually eject it, such as the old paperclip trick? Also, did it shutdown because although the disk is Tiger... which it should run, the installation disk was not configured for the iBook?

Comment: Is it not powering up as in not booting or does it not do anything at all when you press the power button?

Comment: It does nothing when I press the power button.

Answer (score 1):

Press the power button then hold the spacebar down.

If the keyboard is working, the system firmware will interpret that as a request to force eject the CD/DVD before continuing to start the OS.

Unless the firmware or hardware are faulty - then you might need to disassemble things to rescue the CD.

Comment: Pressing the power button and space key had no effect.